# Android webview looks different than PC browser

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

i loaded html contents having js form assets in Android webview.but there is much difference between how it looks in Android webview and PC browser.
Also i had enable loadjavascript and used weviewclient but still having difference.
Please suggest what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots showing how they are different?

Comment: Help us help you. as @Asok wrote, give us some screenshots. Or just some mockups from Paint.

Answer (score 1):

The Android browser might draw things differently or interpret JavaScript differently from your PC browser.

Every browser has a different javascript implementation. You might be able to get around that by using jQuery or something similar.

Android might draw some elements differently to make them fit better on the small screen.

Also, CSS is not working in the same way in all browsers.